# css path do not work (php)

Tags: php, css

I am trying to make a simple application in PHP (MVC). I made the routing and in Views i created an inc folder where head.php - header.php - footer.php exists. The head.php is included in header.php. In the head.php title there is a $pageTitle variable. The thing is that when i include the header.php in other files even if the $pageTitle is changing (according to the new value) no styles from css file is presented!!!

my head.php file is

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $pageTitle ?></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="../src/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../src/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../src/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

my header.php is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<?php 
define( 'ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) );

include( ROOT_DIR.'/inc/head.php' );
// include 'inc/head.php';
// include '../app/views/inc/head.php'; 
?>
```

and i include the header

```
<?php 
$pageTitle = "login-register | Twitter";

define( 'ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) );
include( ROOT_DIR.'/inc/header.php' );

// include '../app/views/inc/header.php'; 


?>
```

I tried many different options but nothing worked. I searched and tried everything (i think)

Comment: What is the browser output for the CSS path?

Comment: Well i do not why but there is two src folders instead of one!!!!

src/src/css/main.css . But it should be src/css/main.css

Comment: @Stergiosm what is the path to the /src/css from the root of the application?

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. Really easy. The browser output showed me that i shouldn't write the src folder at the link in the head.php file.

Comment: Don't be lazy using relative urls. Always use Absolute urls. eg. `/src/css/main.css`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a relative path to your /src/css and /src/js, try using an absolute path like this -

```html
<link href="/src/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/src/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/src/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths to include the CSS. Relative paths will be relative to the current url in the address bar (which might have a subdirectory in it).

To check the result of a relative path copy the relative path from the `href` to the clipboard (ctrl+c) and append it to the address that is already in the browser address bar.

Example 1:
Href value: `../src/css/main.css`
Address bar initial value: `http://example.com/directory/file.ext`
Modified address bar value: `http://example.com/directory/../src/css/main.css`

The result of the above example will be computed as `http://example.com/src/css/main.css` which should normally be correct.

Example 2:
Href value: `../src/css/main.css`
Address bar initial value: `http://example.com/directory/file.ext`
Modified address bar value: `http://example.com/directory/../src/css/main.css`

The result of the above example will be computed as `http://example.com/subdirectory/src/css/main.css` which isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How the folder structure looks like? maybe you do not need to put src for the path, or maybe you do not need to go up one folder from the path.

Comment: My login form is in the Twitter/app/views/login.php
The header.php is in the Twitter/app/views/inc/header.php
the head.php is in the Twitter/app/views/inc/head.php
and finally the css file is in the Twitter/src/css/main.css